# Reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type... not working with custom classes?

Tags: java, java-8

According to the documentation on "method references", it's possible to create:

> Reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type

Link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html

I wrote the following code:

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Function<String, String> f1 = String::toString;

        Function<String, String> f2 = App::toString; // Compilation error
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

However the "method reference" using the class "String" compiles fine, whereas the same "method reference" using my own App class doesn't compile fine.

Can someone tell why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a class method reference, the first Function type parameter is the type of the class and the second is the return type of the function.  Try:

```
Function<App, String> f2 = App::toString;
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be `Function<App, String> f2`

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is `Function<App, String> f2`.